# Parsing an element by class name on data method in jsoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup

So I have this project where I have to log in to a site and extract some data using Java.

I am using jsoup and I found all the required inputs for the site apart from one.

One input (element) that I need to fill in has no name or id, just a class name named like `btn btn-primary btn login` with value `Logga in`.

More specifically :

`<input type="SUBMIT" class="btn btn-primary btn-login" value="Logga in">`

Does anyone have an idea how to parse it to the data field and create the cookie I need so I can get an active connection to all the other sub URLs I am using?

Comment: From what I remember `<input type="SUBMIT" ..>` simply renders button for user to click, so form could be send to server. Its `value` should represent only button's label and shouldn't be part of data processed by server. What makes you think that it is that input which you need to "fill"?

Comment: @Pshemo i tried that 2 days ago because it had a name and i managed to log in, but when i tried to update a set i am keeping i didnt manage to log in, then i checked the developer tab on google chrome and the input did not have a name. I am guessing they changed it for some reason(maybe think i was trying to hack the site?).